# Function/dom calls in javascript library

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a javascript library like jquery. I get how to create a normal library like so:

```
 var lib=lib||(function () {
       function privateFunction (alert ("hi");){};
       return {
          exampleAlert: function(input){
          alert(input);
       }
     }
    })();
```

Calling it like so:

```
lib.exampleAlert ("test");
```

This is like jquery

```
 $.ajax(stuffhere);
```

My question revolves around jquery. It can call the dom like $('.class').hide() and have functions like $.ajax(stuffhere); in the same library. How can I do dom calls and a regular function call like the ajax one in the above example library?

Thanks in advance!! Have searched more days than I would like to admit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM has nothing to do here, it is just up to jQuery implementation.
If you ask about having both `lib()` and `lib.func()` calls, then you can do the following to support both function types at the same time:

```
var lib = function(sel) {
    return {
        object: document.querySelector(sel),
        text: function(val) {
           if (val === undefined) {
               return this.object.innerText;
           } else {
               this.object.innerText = val;
           }
        } 
    };        
};

lib.ajax = function() {
    console.log("AJAX imitation");
};
```

Now, you can do both:

```
lib("body").text("hi"); // jQuery-style setter
var text = lib("body").text(); // jQuery-style getter, returns "hi"
```

and

```
lib.ajax();
```

jQuery works exactly in the same way, but hundred times more complex.

Comment: Is that the best practice of doing that type of support? If it is, thank you so very much!

Comment: @coolkzchris In general, it is pretty unusual. However, jQuery uses this approach and many modern JS plugins use the same. So, now, it is a good and well-known practice.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed to know.